# 'It's the ducks!'

Tags: grammar

'It's the ducks!', Peppa Pig exclaims in one episode, according to a student of mine.
I can't for the life of me explain to him why.
Research on here has led me to 'dummy it'.
Am I right?

Comment: Explain why ... _what_? Why Peppa Pig exclaimed as she did? Also, what do you mean by 'dummy it'?

Comment: Someone said that someone said... please at least link to the clip with a time spot.

Comment: *It is raining.  It is the ducks.*  -  Same thing. Dummy "it"